# Temps historique ou histoire de temps

Tags: traduction, abréviations

Je cherche deux choses :

- La traduction de ***Time History*** (a history of time intervals or a list of time intervals).
- Son abréviation. Quelque chose comme ***Time Hist***. Je n'ai pas beaucoup de caractères pour écrire cette abréviation.

C'est possible que j'ai besion "Journal de temps".

I have data that is captured in regular intervals (Time History).  We use the term Time History as a way to denote the passage of time and data summed, averaged and calculated on each interval.  So maybe I need something other than a direct translation, though we would like to keep the terms close so when speaking with a native French speaker in English when we say Time History they understand which section of data we are talking about.

Comment: *L'histoire des temps*, peut-être ?

Comment: Chronologie ou historique (des intervalles).

Comment: Could you clarify the context? The connection between the expression "time history" and your definition is not clear to me, i.e. I might be confused by your presentation in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Time history* → « **Historique des intervalles** (de temps) » ou « **Chronologie des intervalles** (de temps) ». S'il n'y a pas d'autres intervalles, il est inutile de préciser « de temps ».
- *Time hist* → « **Histor. interv.** », « **Chronol. interv.** » ou simplement « **Historique** / **Chronologie** » s'il n'y a pas d'autres historiques à représenter.

Note: historique est ici utilisé comme substantif avec cette [définition du TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/historique):

> II. − Subst. masc. sing. Exposé chronologique de faits passés appartenant à la vie collective ou individuelle. Hugo (...) me fait (...) un petit cours d'esthétique qui (...) me semble l'historique des évolutions de son esprit (Goncourt, Journal,1872, p. 888).Il avait écrit l'historique de l'affaire [de Panama] (Léautaud, Journal, t. 1, 1903, p. 77).

Pour la différence entre les deux termes proposés : **chronologie** décrit l'ordre dans lequel un ensemble d'événements qui ont un lien entre eux se sont succédé alors qu'**historique** décrit une suite indéfinie d'événements qui se sont succédé sans qu'il y ait nécessairement de lien entre eux. Je pencherait donc pour **historique** après la mise à jour de la question.

Comment: J'aime Chronologie.  Et si on faisait l'abréviation: Chrono?

Comment: Oui, pourquoi pas. « Chrono. » est parfois employé pour « chronologie » quand il n'y ne risque pas d'y avoir de confusion avec le plus courant « chronomètre » et ses dérivés.

Comment: After your edit, my guess is *Historique* is what would be used in French. Unless I'm missing something about your context, I see no reason to specify this history is about time, given the fact an history is by definition related to the passing of time.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is " l'histoire du temps ". Because the history is about time. The other one you mentioned would have been "Historic Time". Here, 'historic' means somewhere in the past while 'history' means story. The two different meanings also occur in French.

Comment: "History" translates to either *histoire* or *historique*. The latter isn't necessarily an adjective in French, unlike "historic" in English.

Answer (score 1):

"chronologie" would be the snapiest and most recognizable.  "chron." if you really need to compress the space